# Modify User Alert with SharePoint Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow, alert, custom-alert-templates

I am looking a way to modify the user alert based on a list element field using the Sharepoint Workflow but I don't achieve it.

The only way to assess something close to it is to send a mail on element modification... but by this way, it's not possible to get in the mail changes on the element.
Have someone any idea on how to deal with it, getting in the mail the modification of the element?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are talking about workflows when item is edited in the list.
in that case -

1. After creating a workflow--> Go to workflows settings.
2. Under Start option ---> tick--> Start workflows automatically when workflows is changed.
3. Save & Publish

Done!!

Comment: Thanks for that. I achieved to do that but I want that the mail send the track changes of the element. So I need to define a workflow which indicates/create/modify the alert on the element :)

Comment: Then you need to put conditions like - If 'column' is equal to 'value' then email 'these users', kind of according to the need

Answer (score 0):

You can use Alert me option, when anything changes it sends an email alert with changes.

Reference:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-an-alert-to-get-notified-when-a-file-or-folder-changes-in-sharepoint-e5a79e7b-a146-46da-a9ef-d65409ba8918#Pick_tab=2007